# Create View using Linked Server db in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, linked-server

How can I create View on Linked Server db. For Example I have a linked server [1.2.3.4] on [5.6.7.8]. Both db servers are SQL Sserver 2005. I want to create View on [5.6.7.8] using table on linked server.

**EDIT:**

On creating using full name, [1.2.3.4].db.dbo.table, I am getting this error.

SQL Execution Error.

Executed SQL statement: SELECT * FROM  1.2.3.4.db.dbo.table ***(YOu can see brackets are not there.)***
Error Source: .Net SqlClient Data Provider
Error Message: Incorrect syntax near '0.0'. ---> part of IP address.

I am just creating this in ManagementStudio, not using it because it is not created yet. I Have changed IP. In image you can see there are not brackets around IP but I given it and on error these brackets are removed.

Thanks.

Comment: Please post full (or more of) the view creation script, as well as the code used to access the view.

Comment: 555.555.555.555 is not a valid IP address. Each number can be a maximum of 255 and it needs to be a valid IP address. For example, you should be able to ping the IP address: ping 10.1.16.1. Often it makes more sense to use the server name rather than the IP address.

Comment: Thanks for your response. 555.555.555.555 is not the IP i am using. I have changed this deliberately.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You need to use the four part qualified name: linkedserver.database.schema.table

```
SELECT * FROM [1.2.3.4].Northwind.dbo.Customers
```

Here is an MSDN article about [accessing object names](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187879.aspx).

You might want to try manually creating the view, rather than using the SQL Management tools:

```
CREATE VIEW [dbo].[sywx]
AS
    SELECT  *
    FROM    [1.2.3.4].Atia.dbo.IpPbxDCR
GO
```

I also recommend that you use a name, if possible, for the linked server rather than using the IP address.

Answer (score 13):

Its a SQL Management Studio Issue. 
If you try to create the view using management studio NEW VIEW then you get that error incorrect syntax.

But if you use SQL Query:

```
CREATE VIEW [dbo].[viewname] 
AS 
    SELECT  * 
    FROM    [0.0.0.0].database.dbo.table 
GO
```

then it will work.

To test you will see the view created when you refresh views. 
If you just do a select query from the view you will see the view return results.

But if you try to go into design mode for that view and try executing the design query the error will pop up again even though the view was successfully created.

Comment: thanks a million for this. My linked server has a hyphen in the name which throws out Management Studio 2005. Your solution works around this.

Comment: That was the issue I was having. I was giving the 'Unresolved object' warning too much importance. Thanks Phil.

Answer (score 2):

If the linked server is set up, you just reference tables on it using a four-part qualified name:

```
linkedserver.database.schema.table
```

So if your linked server name is [0.0.0.0], you can reference a table as:

```
[0.0.0.0].database.schema.table
```

Answer (score 2):

your main problem is naming your Link Server with numbers (IP address). The only way that worked for me was using an alphabetical name for my Link Server without any dot '.'
You can use these lines of code to add your link server and authentication:

```
    EXEC sp_addlinkedserver   
        @server='TEST_LINK', 
        @srvproduct='',
        @provider='SQLNCLI', 
        @datasrc='tcp:0.0.0.0'

    EXEC sp_addlinkedsrvlogin
        @useself='FALSE',
        @rmtsrvname='TEST_LINK',
        @rmtuser='user',
        @rmtpassword='secret'
```

You can find the original answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/841339/having-trouble-adding-a-linked-sql-server/2469545#2469545)

Comment: An IP works fine as long as you enclose the address in square brackets.

Comment: This is a great solution to create de linked server with an alias when your DNS doesn't resolve names correctly.

Answer (score 1):

For linked servers using the periods for a web service name - this won't work.
The code details and steps of the difference is posted at:
http://www.access-programmers.co.uk/forums/showthread.php?t=260764

e.g.  `FROM [V2.EGG.COM]..[NAT_DBA].[NV_WELLS]`
In SSMS 2008, the square brackets around the [V2.EGG.COM].. are removed by the editor. Then the update failes because it is more than 4 parts.
Have searched in vain to find a work-around.
The Script that does work is posted at the link above.

Answer (score 0):

You can also just drag and drop the table/view object from the linked server into your view and Management Studio will create the four part reference for you.

Comment: Dragging and dropping from a defined linked server into my view in management studio didn't work - the interface (Management Studio 2008) doesn't allow me to drag and drop. Maybe there's a setting in the linked server that prevents this?

Answer (score 0):

You need to define a Linked Server before you can access it, since the linked server entry also contains the authentication details.

After creating a linked server, you can access its databases and their objects using the dot notation servername.database.[owner].object