# Linq to SQL union data from two tables into single IEnumerable/IQueryable

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq, linq-to-sql, .net-4.0

I have two log tables in seperate SQL Server databases (on different servers).  The two tables have exactly the same schema. In my .NET application I can create two Linq to SQL class collections (DBML files) and then do my own custom Linq queries to union the two tables and return an anonymous type.  But I have several queries (all slightly different) on the same tables and doing the unions every time is repetitive.

Is it possible to union the two tables into a single concrete/named type IEnumerable?  Basically what I'd like to do is something like:

```
var logs = Logs.Where(l => l.TimeStart >= DateTime.Today)
```

And have `Logs` actually return data from two tables and have sensible queries sent to the two database servers no matter what I put in the `.Where()`.

Is this possible?

Comment: Can you show us the code of your union?

Comment: I'm actually using the FullOuterJoin extension method from [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13503860/62072) SO answer.

Comment: @TomHunter Have you tried creating a separate class and have the union being returned as an object as part of the class new()? That way in your code you just create a new instance of the class ( and the union etc is done as part of the new() sub)

Comment: @TomHunter Hope that makes some sort of sense...

Comment: I think it's actually an IQueryable that I need.  I need sensible queries sent to the database no matter what kind of filtering I use in my `Where()`.

Comment: @TomHunter In that case, you could create a class which defines your IQueryable and then you can make your queries types of that class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that out of the box you cannot get one IQueryable covering multiple datacontexts. You mention you have

> seperate SQL Server databases (on different servers).

A solution might be to create a linked view. Example: [Create View using Linked Server db in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2493866/532498)

Once you have the linked view, the query will be fairly simple and straigtforward.

Comment: I was hoping to avoid making any changes/adding views to the databases.