# SSRS - Setting value of text box from another dataset?

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I have a report with a list attached to a dataset with the following columns, and the list is grouped on id:

- id
- sale_date

I have another dataset2 that contains the following:

- id
- customer_name
- customer_phone

Unfortunately, I cannot join the two tables as they are in different databases, so my question is:

How do I show the customer_name in a textbox within the list so that when the reader forwards through the ids, the correct customer_name displays in the textbox?

I tried putting this expression in the textbox, but it doesn't return anything when I forward through the records:
=lookup(fields!id.value,fields!id.value,fields!customer_name.value,"dataset2")

Thank you for your help.

Update: In the interest of moving on, I found an alternative to my problem by using a switch statement in the textbox's expression to populate its value based upon the id.  I know it's a hack, but since there are only 10 customer_name's, it's not too bad.  I would like to resolve with using the dataset2 data in future.

Answer (score 0):

You do not say which database system you are using. I'm assuming SQL Server.

There is nothing to stop you - from a SQL Server point of view - in [connecting data from one database to another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17951320/create-view-across-multiple-databases).

You can even connect to two databases on [two different servers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2493866/create-view-using-linked-server-db-in-sql-server).

SSRS will almost always perform better (and be easier to maintain for you) if you sort your datasets out before they get into the report.

Comment: I am using sql server, but unfortunately I do not have access to the underlying db to create a view, so I have to bring in the data from the two tables as separate datasets.

Comment: How are the datasets populated?

Comment: I have two datasources, which I use to create the two datasets directly from the db tables.

Comment: Yes - but how are the populated? Select * from table? EXEC sp_StoredProc?